# Angular2 FileTransfer.upload response not updating in view

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

Below is my code.  The sendFile function works fine and I can log the result to the console in the win function but the variable will not update in the view.

```
constructor(zone:NgZone) {
  this.res = [];
  this.zone = new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false});
}

win(r) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    var temp = JSON.parse(r.response)
    temp = temp.ParsedResults[0].ParsedText
    temp = temp.split('\n');

    //this var is not updated in the view

    this.res = temp

    //this works fine

     console.log(temp);

  });
}


sendFile(imageURI){
  var file = new FileUploadOptions();
  file.fileKey="file";
  file.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'.jpg';
  file.mimeType="text/plain";

  var params = new Object();
  params.apikey = "helloworld";
  file.params = params;

  var ft = new FileTransfer();
```

the `win` function doesn't seem to have access to `this.res`

```
  ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://myserver"), this.win, this.fail, file);
}

scanImage(){
  let options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,//DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    allowEdit: true,
    targetHeight: 1000,
    correctOrientation: true
  };

navigator.camera.getPicture(
  (imageURI) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
```

the img updates in the view

```
      this.imageSrc = imageURI;
      this.sendFile(imageURI);
    });
  },

  (error) => {
    console.log('error');
  }, options

);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind function when referencing them:

```
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://myserver"),
          this.win.bind(this), this.fail.bind(this), file);
```

Otherwise the `this` you use in these functions won't correspond to the instance of the component itself. So using `this.res` in the `win` method this way won't update the `res` property of the component...

Another point. Why do you instantiate an `NgZone` manually instead of using the injected one?

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
  this.res = [];
}

win(r) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    (...)
  });
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  As for NgZone... no reason.  New to angular so just a rookie mistake.  I'll do it this way from now on.